# How to undef few flags assigned to a variable in one make file in another make file called recursively?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In makefile 1:

```
CC_FLAGS += -std=gnu99
CC_FLAGS += -g
```

In makefile 2:

```
CC_FLAGS += -std=c99
```

called by make file 1 recursively. How to undef which was defined in makefile 1?

Answer (score 0):

You do not really give enough details, like, for instance, where makefile 2 is included in makefile 1, compared to where the `CC_FLAGS` variable is assigned and evaluated. Anyway, here is a proposal that will maybe give you some ideas to solve your problem:

In makefile 1:

```
LOCAL_CC_FLAGS_1 := -std=gnu99 -g
...
<target>: <prerequisites>
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $(LOCAL_CC_FLAGS_1) ...
```

In makefile 2:

```
LOCAL_CC_FLAGS_2 := -g
...
<target>: <prerequisites>
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $(LOCAL_CC_FLAGS_2) ...
```